# converting string stream to char*

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
const char * getFileName(std::string filePath, std::string theDestDirectory)
{
    size_t lastOfParentDirectory = filePath.find_last_of("\\");
    size_t extentionPos = filePath.substr(lastOfParentDirectory + 1).find_last_of(".");
    std::stringstream convertedFilePath;
    convertedFilePath << theDestDirectory << "\\" << filePath.substr(lastOfParentDirectory + 1).substr(0, extentionPos) << ".stl";
    return convertedFilePath.str().c_str();
}
```

what I am trying to do is to get new file path and change the extention of the file. I need the output to be of type const char * since the other processing sould be in char *

the upper code compiles but give a nonsence output[image: output]

Comment: `getFileName` returns a pointer to local object's internals. By the time it returns, the returned pointer is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `convertedFilePath` variable is local inside the `getFileName` function. Once the function returns the stream is destructed, and the string it holds is destructed with it. That means the pointer you return now points to a destructed string, and dereferencing it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The simple solution is of course to return a `std::string` instead. If you need a `const char*` later, you can always use the `c_str` function on the returned object.

Answer (score 3):

You simply return a pointer to an object witch dies before you use the string.

```
std::stringstream convertedFilePath;  // object start living
return convertedFilePath.str().c_str(); // return pointer to inside the object
} // the object convertedFilePath is dead and the memory is not longer usable
```

Possible solution:

1. return the object itself ( convertedFilePath )
2. generate the object before and pass it as reference to your function
3. pass a pointer to a char* where the memory it points to is big enough 
   and copy the content of convertedFilePath.c_str() into the area before
   your function ends